# Can we prove that a constant central force pointed towards a point produces circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation, angular-velocity

I was analysing the motion of a body when a single, radially inward force acts on a body, and I was trying to prove this is indeed circular motion, using geometry and looking at what happens at infinitesimal time scales. I ofcourse have been taught that this force is the reason for circular motion but let's forget that for a moment. When I think about the infinitesimal distances travelled in dt time difference, there is ofcourse a motion due to the initial velocity, along the tangential direction, and a small movement along the radially inward direction, due to the force. But when analysing in such small length scales, which operation happens first, or does both happen at the same instant? (The downward and sideways motion, due to the force and the velocity respectively). How to analyse the geometry of the case and come to the conclusion that this indeed will follow a circle equation?

Comment: Are you referring to a force of the form $\vec F = -F_0 \hat r$, where $F_0$ is a constant?

Comment: I'd also like to add another question: How can we prove that this force doesn't cause any magnitude increment in the inward direction, and this changing the overall magnitude of the velocity vector? Even if we apply sine small angle approx, sinx≈x, which means there is some infinitely small d∅ that changes the direction, which consequently proves there is an infinitely small sin d∅ which also has to add up over a finite period

Comment: @J.Murray yes, but not explicitly stated like that. I start with a particle projected with a v_0 velocity, and i subject it to a force (let's say initially the particle moves in x hat direction, and the force, initially is in the y hat downward direction) which obeys the condition that it is always constant, and is always pointing towards an arbitrary point. Can we prove that the path is indeed circular without assuming it up top?

Comment: It can produce circular motion, but doesn't have to. If you start at rest in such a field, motion will be a line straight toward the origin.

Comment: That's why I give it an initial velocity perpendicular to the force @mmesser314

Comment: If you pick the right velocity, it will be circular.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_force, and the comments therein on Kepler's laws?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking about a charged particle in a uniform magnetic field? That trajectory is always circular if the motion is perpendicular to the field (a helix in general). There, $F = qvxB$, which is always perpendicular to $v$. Since there is no component parallel to $v$, the speed never changes, which means the magnitude of $F$ never changes. A constant sideways force on a particle with a constant velocity produces a path with constant curvature, which is circular.

Comment: Well My doubt is, can we view this mechanism in terms of small increments in distances along the radially inward, and tangentially outward directions, along with a radially downward increment in velocity? There seems to be a problem, either with the logic or my understanding, that if these small angles that come up due to the downward acceleration actually mean something and add up to give a finite difference in angle, why can't the velocity increase so too?

Comment: Your thinking is in the right direction. If the force is constant and towards a point, the angle can change. The particle can acquire a radial component of velocity. Its speed can change. The problem is your statement that the orbit must be a circle. It can take other shapes. In the solar system (not a constant force, but centrally directed), orbits of planets happen to be nearly circular. But in general, they are elliptical. It would be similar in your problem.

Comment: Ok, you seem to make a good point with the elliptical orbits. So the motion can be of any sort and f=mv^2/r is a special case  with circular orbits then? There seems to be a gap in my understanding of fundamental mechanics.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the motion in your problem will turn out to be elliptical. But the central point will be in the center of the ellipse.

Comment: Yes, you are right, now I am wondering how to prove its an ellipse. I read some stuff @MartinC. Sent and some stuff below that, I think this is close to what i was thinking https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem . Unfortunately upon reading this article, i realised I don't have enough knowledge on vector calculus, as in I don't know how the curl of some conservative force should behave in which situation. I suppose this question can be closed now

Comment: Because both are infinitesimal, it does not matter which one is first, they do not affect each other.

Comment: It's a differential equation.  I think you're looking for the solution to the [_Binet equation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation) specifically.  See also [what would a planetary orbit look like if gravity had constant magnitude](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345571/what-would-a-planetary-orbit-look-like-if-gravity-had-constant-magnitude) over at _mathematics_ stack exchange.

Comment: @wyck yeah after reading the wiki page which speaks about the central force problem I realised I don't know enough about vector calculus, reading up on that currently. I saw that they used potential functions and the property of conservative forces, which I could understand. The curl and the other stuff like setting up the Euler Lagrange equation and stuff, i didn't understand (that's where my knowledge level is currently), so I'm reading up on that. If some mod could close this question it would be good

Comment: What does radially inward mean for a particle moving in an arbitrary direction at an arbitrary speed in an arbitrary coordinate system?

Comment: Dear @JEB ,the coordinate system can be anything, I'm just giving you the fact that there is a force acting towards a point o all the time, and the particle has a velocity initially of value v_0, again, initially perpendicular to the force vector. Can I get the coordinates of the particle at any time t?

Comment: @nickbros123 That is the point of my question. If the coordinate system can be anything, how can you talk about "radially inward forces"--that is a coordinate system dependent concept. The modern concept of "geometry" (which you want to use) in physics is a coordinate-free formulation, so you should be able to express the problem in coordinate free notation (that is: in terms of scalar dot products, vectors, and axial-vector cross products), sans coordinates. Once you bring in coordinates, as far as I can tell it can be reduced to $r=R$ and $\dot\theta =\omega = v/R$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the general case you obtain those equations of motion. (the position vector to the mass is given with polar coordinates).

$$\ddot r-r\phi^2=\frac Fm\tag 1$$
and
$$r\,\ddot\phi+2\dot r\dot\phi=0\quad\Rightarrow \dot\phi=\frac{L}{r^2}\tag 2$$

thus only if

$$ F=-m\,r\phi^2\quad \Rightarrow\\
\ddot r=0\quad ,r(t)=r_0=\text{constant}$$

and from equation (2)

$$\dot\phi=\frac{L}{r_0^2}=\omega=\text{constant}$$

thus the force $~F=-m\,r_0\,\omega^2~$

Answer (score 6):

> How to analyse the geometry of the case and come to the conclusion that this indeed will follow a circle equation?

You'd have to make a mistake, because in general this will **not** generate a circular trajectory.  Explicitly, let the particle start at the point $(0,R_0)$ with initial velocity $(v_0, 0)$, and let the force $\vec F = -F_0 \hat r$ pull the particle toward the origin.  The resulting motion will be circular if and only if
$$F_0 = \frac{mv_0^2}{R_0}$$
as per the standard centripetal force equation.  In general of course this need not be true; for a given force $F_0$, you may choose $v_0$ and $R_0$ completely arbitrarily and they need not satisfy this condition. If they don't, then the resulting motion will not be circular.

Comment: Ok i agree I made a mistake, the f=mv^2/r condition is important, but still, let's say the velocity is satisfying the equation above, or let's adjust the radius (the distance between particle and this arbitrary point I was talking about), can we prove it then? I want to understand how the infinitesimal length differences and velocity differences compound up to give me a circle. I couldn't find the exposition about this

Comment: @nickbros123 In the OP and subsequent comments, you're asking how to prove that a constant force toward a fixed point produces circular motion, and the answer is that you can't because it doesn't. But it sounds like your real question is something like "how can we view circular motion in terms of infinitesimal displacements", is that accurate?

Comment: yes you are right, in that I want to understand where the circle comes from, preferably by analysing the infinitesimal changes in length and or velocity. About the proof that it will be a circle, i read your other answer here and I have tweaked the question such that it obeys f=mv^2/r property.

Answer (score 2):

The thing with infinitesimal amounts is that they do not have time to make a difference.

- You start out with an initial velocity.
- Then you pull perpendicularly to that speed with a force.
- That perpendicular force causes a perpendicular acceleration
- which in turns creates a new, perpendicular velocity component.

With this new component added (via vector addition) to the initial velocity as another component, then you get a resultant velocity which now is slightly angled.

But this inwards velocity component is actually not happening! You, by definition, adjust your force immediately so that it always is perpendicular, and you thus also adjust the force angle to the new slightly angled velocity. Because you constantly at every single moment keep the force perpendicular, then no magnitude of velocity will ever be induced in this inwards directly.

Comment: I don't seem to understand how infinitesimal distances and or angles work here. I will think about this more and read some stuff and get back to your answer. On first viewing I don't agree with this

Comment: @nickbros123 I'd suggest a second viewing then.

Comment: Infinitesimals don't come intuitively to me. I'm finding it hard to wrap my head around this
 "But this inwards velocity component is actually not happening! You, by definition, adjust your force immediately so that it always is perpendicular, and you thus also adjust the force angle to the new slightly angled velocity. Because you constantly at every single moment keep the force perpendicular, then no magnitude of velocity will ever be induced in this inwards directly."

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, in general there will not just be circular motion, however from yourcomments I'd assume you'd want to prove that circular motion is A solution.

Given my radial force has the correct magnitude:

$$\vec{F}= -\frac{m|\vec{v}|^2}{r} \hat r $$

Applying newtons laws:

$$m\vec{a} = -\frac{m|\vec{v}|^2}{r} \hat r $$

Let's assume that there exists A solution in the form of a 2D circular trajectory.

$$\vec{x}(t) = r \cos(\omega t) \hat i  + r\sin(\omega t) \hat j$$

Differentiating

$$v(t) = -r\omega t \sin(\omega t)\hat i + r\omega \cos(\omega t) \hat j$$

$$|\vec{v}(t)|^2 = r^2\omega^2$$

Differentiating again

$$\vec{a}(t)= -r\omega^2  \cos(\omega t)\hat i - r\omega^2 \sin(\omega t) \hat j$$
$$\vec{a}(t) = -r\omega^2 \hat r$$

Substitute our trial solution into our differential equation.

$$-r\omega^2 \hat r = -r\omega^2 \hat r $$

$$1=1$$

Thus a circular path, is a specific solution to this differential equation

Comment: I somewhat agree with this proof, but it's like doing it post facto. Is it possible to get the circle equation without from the forces, as opposed to the forces from the circle equation?

Comment: It's a valid proof, however it is finding a specific  solution to this equation  under the assumption the velocity is perpendicular to the force at all times. It is entirely possible to solve this differential equation without substitution,however the problem becomes increasingly complex since this equation does not need to give rise to circles. Only when the velocity is perpendicular to the force the solution is circular motion.

Comment: Dear @jensenpauli , where can I read more about this proof, and the precursors to this.

Comment: the proof in my original post? This is simply proof by substitution. We trial some function and then substitute it into our differential equation, if the equation is satisfied, then our trial function is a solution of the differential equation, BY DEFINITION. This solution may  not be a general solution , but a particular solution. Most commonly substitution yields what is called a "dispersion relation" which is conditions on e.g free variables I introduce in my trial function. In this case we reach 1=1 and hence my solution is always a solution regardless of $\omega$ , but sometimes

Comment: I will have restrictions  for example; $$\vec{E}\cos(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t) $$ I's a solution to the electromagnetic  wave equation, substitution into the differential equation yields that it is a solution, given $$\frac{\omega }{|\vec{k}|} = c$$ Aka wave speed is of light

Comment: Dear @jensenpaul , I agree with this specific solution proof, and it kind of answers my question. But you seem to know a lot more than just this, do you mind sharing some resources about this and mathematics in classical mechanics in general? I would be able to come to some conclusions myself if i pick up me pencil and do the equations, but I would like a comprehensive view on this. (I am for all intents and purposes self studying physics)